# How do I separate some properties from the main MSBuild file

Tags: .net, msbuild, ant

Ages ago when I was a java developer I could make separate ant scripts that I would call from my main ant script. I would put properties unique to each environment where my main script would run. I want to do the same thing in MSBuild but I can't find out how to chain MSBuild scripts together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) them.

```
   <Import Project="MyTargets" Condition="Exists('MyTargets')"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The import is definitely useful, you can also actively invoke other projects:

```
<MSBuild Projects="Other.proj" Properties="SomeProp=$(MyProperty)" />
```